# Split de texto em excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, funções

Tenho que dividir as células de "Nome Completo" da minha tabela em duas.

Portanto, utilizei duas funções: "Esquerda" para pegar o Nome da pessoa e "Direita" para pegar o sobrenome. Nas quais, tudo o que estiver até o primeiro espaço é considerado nome, e o tudo o que estiver até o último espaço é sobrenome.

Então, se o "Nome Completo" está registrado como "Mateus Binatti", Nome = Mateus, Sobrenome = Binatti. Ou, se o "Nome Completo" está registrado como "Mateus de Binatti", Nome = Mateus, Sobrenome = de Binatti. Até aí, tudo bem.

Porém, se o usuário cadastrou o nome dele como sendo apenas Mateus, o campo de nome e sobrenome retornam #VALOR, o que é plausível, afinal não existe espaço no preenchimento.

Gostaria de saber jeitos de complementar a minha fórmula para poder erradicar estas questões.

Fórmula para nome

```
=ESQUERDA($A2;LOCALIZAR(" "; $A2;1))
```

Fórmula para sobrenome

```
=DIREITA($A2;NÚM.CARACT($A2)-LOCALIZAR(" ";$A2;1))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizar estas fórmulas:

```
=SEERRO(ESQUERDA($A3;LOCALIZAR(" ";$A3;1));$A3)

=SEERRO(DIREITA($A3;NÚM.CARACT($A3)-LOCALIZAR(" ";$A3;1));"")
```

Em que se houver erro na parte esquerda do nome, o valor da coluna A será escrito.
E se houver erro na parte direita do nome, será escrito "" ou Blank

### Atualização

Uma **UDF** (Função definida pelo usuário) pode ser usada para realizar estas operações.
Basta colocar a função dentro de um módulo do VBA.

#### Código

```
Function EXTRACTELEMENT(Txt As String, n, Separator As String) As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
    EXTRACTELEMENT = Split(Application.Trim(Mid(Txt, 1)), Separator)(n - 1)
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    ' error handling code
    EXTRACTELEMENT = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Após inserir no módulo pode utilizá-la na planilha da seguinte forma:

Os dados são inseridos com `=EXTRACTELEMENT("String para separar ou célula com a String"; "Número do Elemento"; "separador(- .,:)")`

A célula `A1` possui a entrada desejada, você pode utilizar a função  `=EXTRACTELEMENT($A$1;1;"-")` na célula `B1` e `=EXTRACTELEMENT($A$1;2;"-")` na célula `B2` e assim por diante.

O resultado:

[image: Resultado]

#### Descrição:

A descrição pode ser adicionada rodando o código a seguir uma vez:

```
Sub DescribeFunction()
   Dim FuncName As String
   Dim FuncDesc As String
   Dim Category As String
   Dim ArgDesc(1 To 3) As String

   FuncName = "EXTRACTELEMENT"
   FuncDesc = "Returns the nth element of a string that uses a separator character/Retorna o enésimo elemento da string que usa um caractér separador."
   Category = 7 'Text category
   ArgDesc(1) = "String that contains the elements/String que contém o elemento"
   ArgDesc(2) = "Element number to return/ Número do elemento a retornar"
   ArgDesc(3) = "Single-character element separator/ Elemento único separador (spc por padrão)"

   Application.MacroOptions _
      Macro:=FuncName, _
      Description:=FuncDesc, _
      Category:=Category, _
      ArgumentDescriptions:=ArgDesc
End Sub
```

Comment: Deu certo, Daniel.
Mas isso me gerou outra dúvida: 
Caso o usuário não tenha Nome Completo registrado, a função retorna 0. Tentei arrumar a fórmula pois é necessário que o valor retornado seja nulo, mas não sei porque ainda está retornando zero. Segue a minha fórmula 
=SEERRO(SEERRO(ESQUERDA($A2;LOCALIZAR(" ";$A2;1));$A2);" ")

Comment: Neste caso você usa somente o `SE`, que se o valor da coluna A estiver diferente de vazio, o resultado é calculado, caso contrário é vazio. `=SE($A3<>"";SEERRO(ESQUERDA($A3;LOCALIZAR(" ";$A3;1));$A3);"")`