# Separar números e palavras

Tags: excel-vba

Tenho uma base de dados no excel onde na linha/coluna tenho datas e palavras. Inclusive, com datas antes de 1900. E, em algumas ocorrências, apenas o ano com 4 algarismos.

Exemplo:

```
"A1" 20-07-1882 Daniel
```

ou

```
"A2" 1882 João
```

Utilizo, para separar os números das palavras, essa função:

```
Public Function SplitText(pWorkRng As Range, pIsNumber As Boolean) As String
    Dim xLen As Long
    Dim xStr As String
    xLen = VBA.Len(pWorkRng.Value)
    For i = 1 To xLen
        xStr = VBA.Mid(pWorkRng.Value, i, 1)
        If ((VBA.IsNumeric(xStr) And pIsNumber) Or (Not (VBA.IsNumeric(xStr)) And _
                                                    Not (pIsNumber))) Then
            SplitText = SplitText + xStr
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Ela funciona perfeitamente, utilizando o parâmetro "TRUE". Entretanto, no caso da data na forma resumida, dd-mm-aaaa ela remove o traço que separa a data ("-") ficando assim o resultado:

```
20071882
```

A ideia aqui é que o traço não seja removido na ora da separação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Função IsNumeric

A função [IsNumeric()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/isnumeric-function) está sendo utilizada. Em que a descrição é:

> Retorna um valor Boolean que indica se uma expressão pode ser avaliada
>   como um número.

Portanto, a mesma só valida números e o hífen não é incluso.

#### Código de Teste

Este código de teste pode ser utilizado para verificar isto, em que o passo a passo pode ser visto com a tecla <kbd>F8</kbd> e habilitando a janela de verificação imediata.

```
Sub teste()

    Dim xLen As Long
    Dim xStr As String
    pWorkRng = "20-07-1882 Daniel"
    pIsNumber = True
    xLen = VBA.Len(pWorkRng)
    For i = 1 To xLen
        xStr = VBA.Mid(pWorkRng, i, 1)
        Debug.Print xStr
        If ((VBA.IsNumeric(xStr) And pIsNumber)) _
             Or (Not (VBA.IsNumeric(xStr) And Not (pIsNumber))) Then
            Str_f = Str_f + xStr
            Debug.Print Str_f
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

## Solução

Para solucionar o problema, a função deve aceitar se o valor é numérico ou se é hífen: `(VBA.IsNumeric(xStr) Or xStr = "-")`, porém não pode haver hífen no nome da pessoa.

#### Código

```
Public Function SplitText(pWorkRng As Range, pIsNumber As Boolean) As String
    Dim xLen As Long
    Dim xStr As String
    xLen = VBA.Len(pWorkRng.Value)
    For i = 1 To xLen
        Debug.Print xStr
        xStr = VBA.Mid(pWorkRng.Value, i, 1)
        If ((VBA.IsNumeric(xStr) Or xStr = "-") And pIsNumber) _
            Or (Not (VBA.IsNumeric(xStr) Or xStr = "-") And _
                     Not (pIsNumber)) Then
            SplitText = SplitText + xStr
            Debug.Print SplitText
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

## Alternativa

A resposta da pergunta [Split de texto em excel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/242605/75104) possui uma forma alternativa de resolver o seu problema.

Onde a utilização de um separador, no caso um espaço `" "`, pode ser utilizado para dividir a string em elementos e o elemento desejado é escolhido como output.