# Macro no Word para formatar conversas do WhatsApp

Tags: vba, macro, whatsapp, microsoft-word

Olá, eu estou fazendo um macro para editar conversas do WhatsApp.

Quando você acessa o WhatsApp, abre uma conversa, toca nos três pontos do canto superior direito, toca em “Mais”, e em seguida toca em “Enviar por e-mail”, a conversa vem em um arquivo “.txt”.

Eu gostaria de copiar e colar o conteúdo desse arquivo no Word e utilizar esse macro para formatar e editar esse texto para que ele fique mais “apresentável”.

Texto de Entrada:

> 01/12/17, 14:29 - Contato: Bom dia
>
> 01/12/17, 14:29 - Eu: Bom dia, tudo bem?
>
> 02/12/17, 15:00 - Contato: Sim

Texto como eu pretendo que fique:

> 01 de Dezembro de 2017 às 14h29min
>
> Contato: Bom dia
>
> Eu: Bom dia, tudo bem?
>
> 02 de Dezembro de 2017 às 15h00min
>
> Contato: Sim

Texto como está ficando:

> //, : - Contato: Bom dia
>
> //, : - Contato: Bom dia
>
> //, : - Contato: Bom dia
>
> //, : - Contato: Bom dia
>
> //, : - Contato: Bom dia
>
> //, : - Contato: Bom dia
>
> //, : - Contato: Bom dia
>
> 01/12/17, 14:29 - Eu: Bom dia, tudo bem?
>
> 02/12/17, 15:00 - Contato: Sim

Meu código:

```
Sub ConvertWhatsAppText()

    Dim lineText As String, lineResult As String
    Dim aux As String, actualyDate As String
    Dim mChar As String * 1
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, p As Integer, limitC As Integer, limitP As Integer

    Dim numbers As String
    numbers = "0123456789"

    limitP = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count
    p = 1

    For Each singleLine In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs

        If p > limitP Then
            Exit For
        End If

        p = p + 1

        lineText = singleLine.Range.Text
        limitC = Len(lineText)

        For i = 1 To limitC

            If InStr(numbers, Mid(lineText, i, 1)) > 0 Then
                mChar = Mid(lineText, i, 17)

                For j = 1 To Len(mChar)
                    If InStr(numbers, Mid(mChar, j, 1)) > 0 And (j = 1 Or j = 2 Or j = 4 Or j = 5 Or j = 7 Or j = 8 Or j = 11 Or j = 12 Or j = 14 Or j = 15) Then

                    ElseIf Mid(mChar, j, 1) = "/" And (j = 3 Or j = 6) Then

                    ElseIf Mid(mChar, j, 1) = " " And (j = 10 Or j = 16) Then

                    ElseIf Mid(mChar, j, 1) = "," And (j = 9) Then

                    ElseIf Mid(mChar, j, 1) = ":" And (j = 13) Then

                    ElseIf Mid(mChar, j, i) = "-" And (j = 17) Then
                        aux = mChar

                        If Not (actualyDate = aux) Then
                            lineResult = lineResult & vbCrLf & FormatDate(aux) & vbCrLf
                            actualyDate = aux
                        Else
                            lineResult = lineResult & vbCrLf
                        End If

                    Else
                        lineResult = lineResult & Mid(lineText, i, 1)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next j
            Else
                lineResult = lineResult & Mid(lineText, i, 1)
            End If
        Next i
        singleLine.Range.Text = lineResult
    Next singleLine

End Sub

Function FormatDate(x As String) As String

    Dim month As String

    Select Case Mid(x, 4, 2)
        Case "01"
            month = "Janeiro"
        Case "02"
            month = "Fevereiro"
        Case "03"
            month = "Março"
        Case "04"
            month = "Abril"
        Case "05"
            month = "Maio"
        Case "06"
            month = "Junho"
        Case "07"
            month = "Julho"
        Case "08"
            month = "Agosto"
        Case "09"
            month = "Setembro"
        Case "10"
            month = "Outubro"
        Case "11"
            month = "Novembro"
        Case "12"
            month = "Dezembro"
    End Select

    FormatDate = Mid(x, 1, 2) & " de " & month & " de 20" & Mid(x, 7, 2) & " às " & Mid(x, 11, 2) & "h" & Mid(x, 14, 2) & "min"

End Function
```

Antes de declarar limitP e o contador p, quando eu executava o código ele acabava em um loop infinito e travava o Word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma mais simples de fazer o parse do texto é usar a função [`Split`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_split_function.htm).

Se a data e hora já estiver no mesmo formato do idioma do Word você pode converter a data e usar as funções de formatação do próprio VBA.

Deixei também a separação de uma data para outra a partir de intervalo maior que 1 minuto mas você configurar de acordo com o que achar melhor.

Agora é preciso pegar mais textos de exemplo e melhorar a função.

```
Sub ConvertWhatsAppText()

    Dim lineText As String
    Dim lineResult As String
    Dim numbers As String
    Dim tmp() As String

    Dim data As String
    Dim hora As String
    Dim texto As String
    Dim corrente As Date
    Dim ultima As Date
    Dim final() As String
    Dim linha As Integer
    Dim linhas As Integer
    linhas = -1

    For Each singleLine In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs

        lineText = singleLine.range.Text

        If lineText <> "" Then

            tmp = Split(lineText, ", ")

            If UBound(tmp) > 0 Then

                data = tmp(0)
                tmp = Split(tmp(1), " - ")

                If UBound(tmp) > 0 Then

                    hora = tmp(0)
                    tmp = Split(lineText, " - ")
                    texto = ""
                    For linha = 1 To UBound(tmp)
                        If linha > 1 Then
                            texto = texto + " - "
                        End If
                        texto = texto + tmp(linha)
                    Next

                    corrente = CDate(data + " " + hora)

                    If DateDiff("n", ultima, corrente) >= 1 Then
                        linhas = linhas + 1
                        ReDim Preserve final(linhas)
                        final(linhas) = Format(corrente, "Long Date") + " às " + Format(corrente, "Short Time")
                        linhas = linhas + 1
                    End If

                    ultima = corrente

                    ReDim Preserve final(linhas)
                    texto = Replace(texto, vbCrLf, "")
                    texto = Replace(texto, vbCr, "")
                    texto = Replace(texto, vbLf, "")
                    final(linhas) = texto
                    linhas = linhas + 1

                End If

            End If

        End If

    Next singleLine

    If UBound(final) >= 0 Then
        ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory).Delete

        For linha = 0 To UBound(final)
            ActiveDocument.range.InsertAfter final(linha) & vbCrLf
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Um adicional, [este link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/242605/75104) possui uma resposta com a utilização do Split em uma UDF.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente!